# Зацикливание запроса

Tags: vue.js, vuex, nuxt.js, vuetify

Стэк: Vue, Vuex, Vuetify, Nuxt, Express. Есть автокомплит из Vuetify:

```
<v-autocomplete
  hint="Введите название региона"
  :items="regions"
  label="Регион"
  persistent-hint
  prepend-icon="search"
  @update:searchInput="searchRegions">
</v-autocomplete>
```

`:items="regions"` - это `computed`:

```
regions(){
  return this.$store.state.main.regions
}
```

При вводе значения в поле идет поиск:

**1** Происходит событие `@update:searchInput`.

**2** Вызывается `searchRegions`:

```
searchRegions(value){    
  let search = value || '';  
  this.$store.dispatch('main/searchRegions', { search });
}
```

**3** который запускает *action* `searchRegions` во Vuex:

```
searchRegions({commit}, {search}){

  this.$axios.get('/api/****', {
    params: {
      search: search
    }
  })
  .then((response)=>{
    commit('SET_REGIONS', response.data.regionsNames)
  }).catch((err)=>{
    console.log(err)
  })
}
```

**4** После нахождения нескольких регионов происходит запись данных через *commit*:

```
mutations: {
  SET_REGIONS: (state, regions) =>{
    state.regions = regions
  }
},
```

Как только данные заполняются компонент `v-autocomplete` реагирует через `computed` `regions` и отрисовывает найденные значения. Но по какой то причине происходит зацикливание. И этот этап начинает происходить заново (срабатывает *action* -> идет запрос на сервер -> обновляются данные) и так до бесконечности.

Но если сделать к примеру так (захардкодить `computed`):

```
regions() {
  return [1,2,3,4]
}
```

То все Oк. Собственно дело в этом `computed`, но не могу понять в чем именно причина?

Comment: все-таки, скорее всего, дело не в computed, а в событии update. посмотрите в доках, может быть есть другое событие, к кторому можно подвязаться. Либо же, может быть подойдет нативное `change`

Comment: событие нужно именно input, чтобы при пользовательском вводе происходил поиск. В доке v-autocomplete есть событие input, но оно не работает. Именно при вводе эммититься только это событие и больше ничего. V-select c опцией autocomplete вроде хорошо работает, но когда его используешь с опцией autocomplete vue говорит что опция deprecated и используйте v-autocomplete

Comment: Сделал так v-on:input.native="searchRegions"

Comment: @ruslik, в доках есть пример для асинхронной подгрузки из БД для компонента `v-autocomplete`, в котором метод `@update` не упоминается.